# Is the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector applicable for test particle motion around black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, precession, post-newtonian, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

In classical mechanics , the [Laplace-Runge-Lenz (LRL) vector](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector#:%7E:text=In%20classical%20mechanics%2C%20the%20Laplace,planet%20revolving%20around%20a%20star.) is a characteristic feature of the Kepler problem. This enables a very simple discussion of the properties of the orbit for the problem. It is an extra conserved quantity besides the total energy and angular momentum for a particle moving under the influence of an inverse-square force field. More importantly, this is associated with some symmetry of the problem.

However, if we consider motion in the gravitational field of a black hole, the analysis of the orbits of test particles become more complicated and we require to use general relativity.

So, is there any analog of the LRL vector in general relativity? The description of black hole geometry by pseudo-Newtonian potential (e.g., the [Paczynski-Wiita potential](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paczy%C5%84ski%E2%80%93Wiita_potential#:%7E:text=is%20the%20speed%20of%20light,and%20the%20marginally%20bound%20orbit.) for non-rotating black holes) is a well-known concept. Is the LRL vector applicable in such systems for motion around non-rotating black holes having spherical symmetry?

Comment: No, because the LRL vector is only applicable if the potential is $1/r$, i.e. Coulombic or Newtonian, and in GR there is at least a cubic correction. The cubic correction is responsible for the precession of Mercury.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct generalization of the LRL vector for geodesic motion in black hole spacetimes, however there are some concepts in general relativity that play analogous roles:

- **Carter constant**, a [conserved quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carter_constant) for particle motion in Kerr (and related) spacetime.
- **Hidden symmetry**, a more general concept, refers to a situation when dynamics (such as particle motion)  in a given background exhibits a symmetry that does not correspond to an explicit symmetry of that background. Carter constant is a conserved quantity associated with such hidden symmetry generated by rank two Killing tensor, see [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1262) for more details and further examples.
- **Bertrand spacetimes**, a term introduced in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/9/4/016), a class of spacetimes where all bound orbits are closed (the name references [Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) establishing uniqueness of Kepler(-Coulomb) and harmonic oscillator potential). Note, that such spacetimes are neither black holes, nor solutions to Einstein equations for any notable matter models.